# sqlite create ordered partitions based on a column value si.e. dense_rank()

Tags: sql, sqlite

If have the following table@

```
ID     VAR1
--     ----
A      YES
B      YES
C      YES
D      NO
E      YES
F      NO
G      YES
H      YES
```

I would like to create a new partition where VAR1 changes between `YES` and `NO` like so:

```
ID     VAR1    VAR2
--     ----
A      YES     1
B      YES     1
C      YES     1
D      NO      2
E      YES     3
F      NO      4
G      YES     5
H      YES     5
```

Obviously I might use a `dense_rank()` in sql server, but I see no equivalent of this in sqlite.

Any workarounds anyone is aware of?

Comment: What you want is not `dense_rank()`.

Comment: That's not what dense_rank does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is tricky in SQLite, but at least it supports CTEs.  Here is the idea . . pull in the previous value (using a correlated subquery).  Then do a cumulative sum based on logic on that value.

```
with tt as (
      select t.*,
             (select t2.var1
              from t t2
              where t2.id < t.id
              order by t2.id desc
              limit 1
             ) as prev_var1
      from t
     )
select tt.*,
       (select sum(case when prev_var1 is null or prev_var1 <> var1 then 1 else 0 end)
        from tt tt2
        where tt2.id <= tt.id
       ) as var2
from tt;
```

This assumes -- as in the question -- that the ordering is specified by the `id` column.

Comment: thank you Gordon - this was what I was looking for. all the best.